# Graphing the translated trig function $y = 2\cos(3(x - 1)) + 4$

Tags: trigonometry

So for the trig function

$$
y=2\cos(3(x-1))+4
$$
I'm not sure how to draw the graph with a shift of $1$ to the right, would it be preferable to sketch it in radians? Also am I supposed to expand the $3(x-1)$ portion of the function?

Comment: This might help illustrate whats going on http://www.regentsprep.org/regents/math/algtrig/att7/phaseshift.htm

Answer (score 1):

The function $f(x) = 2\cos[3(x - 1)] + 4$ has the form 
$$f(x) = A\cos[B(x - C)] + D$$
where $|A|$ is the amplitude, $|B|$ is the frequency, $C$ is the horizontal shift, $D$ is the vertical shift and $2\pi/|B|$ is the period.  In our example, $A = 2$, $B = 3$, $C = 1$, and $D = 4$.  Hence, our final graph will have amplitude $2$, frequency $3$, period $2\pi/3$, and will be shifted one unit to the right and four units upwards.

The graph of $f(x) = \cos x$ is shown below.

[image: cosine_graph]

The function $f(x) = \cos x$ has amplitude $1$ and period $2\pi$.

The transformation $f(x) \to 2f(x)$ that sends $\cos x \to 2\cos x$ doubles the amplitude of the function, as shown below. The graph of $y = 2\cos x$ has amplitude $2$ and period $2\pi$.

[image: cosine_graph_with_doubled_amplitude]

The transformation $2f(x) \to 2f(3x)$ that sends $2\cos x \to 2\cos(3x)$ triples the frequency of the preceding graph, meaning that three cycles of the graph are completed in each period of the preceding graph, as shown below.
Notice that the graph of $y = 2\cos(3x)$ has amplitude $2$ and period $2\pi/3$.

[image: cosine_graph_with_doubled_amplitude_and_tripled_frequency]

The transformation $2f(3x) \to 2f(3(x - 1))$ that sends $2\cos(3x) \to 2\cos[3(x - 1)]$ shifts the graph of $y = 2\cos(3x)$ one unit to the right, as shown below. Notice that the graph of $y = 2\cos[3(x - 1)]$ has amplitude $2$, period $2\pi/3$, and a horizontal shift of $1$.

[image: horizontal_shift_of_cosine_graph_with_doubled_amplitude_and_tripled_frequency]

Finally, the transformation $2f(3(x - 1)) \to 2f(3(x - 1)) + 4$ that sends $2\cos[3(x - 1)]  \to 2\cos[3(x - 1)] + 4$ shifts the graph of $y = 2\cos[3(x - 1)]$ up by four units, as shown in the graph below.  Notice that the graph of $y = 2\cos[3(x - 1)] + 4$ has amplitude $2$, period $2\pi/3$, a horizontal shift of $1$, and a vertical shift of $4$.

[image: horizontal_and_vertical_shift_of_cosine_graph_with_doubled_amplitude_and_tripled_frequency]

Answer (score 0):

Think of it in multiple phases. The way I would do this is to consider the simplified expression

$$
y = 2 \cos(3x - 3) + 4
$$

Analysing this helps if you know how to analyse the general form of

$$
z(t) = A \cos(\omega t + \phi)
$$

Here, notice that the maximum amplitude for $z$ is $A$, and minimum is $-A$.

When $t = 0$, $z(t = 0)  = A \cos(\phi)$. Here, $\phi$ is called as the **phase** of the function, and it tells you by how much the function is shifted from the actual value of $\cos$ at $0$.

The $\omega$ is called as the **angular velocity**, and it tells you "how fast" the function $z(t)$ repeats.

We know that $\cos$ has a period of $2 \pi$. That is $$\cos (2 \pi + t) = \cos (t )$$

Similarly, the general period for out function $z(t)$ is $T$ such that

$$
z(t + T) = z(t) \\
A \cos (\omega(t + T) + \phi) = A \cos (\omega t + \phi) \\
\cos (\omega(t + T) + \phi) - \cos (\omega t + \phi) = 0
$$

Since the period of $\cos$ is $2 \pi$,

$$
\omega(t + T) + \phi - (\omega t + \phi) = 2\pi \\
\omega t + \omega T + \phi - \omega t - \phi = 2 \pi \\
\omega T = 2 \pi \\
T = \frac{2 \pi}{\omega}
$$

Usually, $T$ is called as the **time period** of $z(t)$ since it tells you after how long the function repeats.

Analysing the function

The given function is
$$
y = 2 \cos(3x - 3) + 4
$$
By comparing with 
$$
z = A \cos(\omega t + \phi)
$$

we know that $A = 2$, $\omega = 3$, $\phi = -3$.

So, the function has a maximum amplitude $2$, It repeats itself after every $\frac{2 \pi}{\omega} = \frac{2 \pi}{3}$, and is shifted to the left by $3$.

The function $y(x)$ also has an extra factor $+4$ which makes the entire function shift by $4$ units upward in the $y$-axis.

Comment: Notice that $\omega t + \phi = 0$ when $t = -\frac{\phi}{\omega}$.  In the case of the function $y = 2\cos[3(x - 1)] + 4$, the argument vanishes when $x = 1$, so the horizontal shift is one unit to the right.